# Xamarin displaying wrong images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms project that started behaving strangely...  It started randomly replacing images with different images from the resource folder.  It seems to only be happening in the Android project, iOS is behaving correctly.  I've removed the recently added images and readded them, clean, rebuild, nothing sees to be helping.  The images that are getting changed are not being overwritten, and the code references the correct file.

Has anyone run into a similar issue before?  Thoughts on how to possibly fix this?

Comment: Is it in a `ListView` by any chance?

Comment: No, it's just an Image inside a ContentView

Comment: You add the images directly in the folder. And After you add in the VS 2015 in folder Resources -> right click -> existing item and add the new images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common behaviour, What I usually do is:

1. Restart Xamarin Studio
2. Go to your project Android location and Delete the bin/Obj folders.
3. Do a full clean, rebuild of your project
4. Delete the Android app from the device

This is the my day to day script. Hope it helps!