# InitializeComponent does not exist

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
InitializeComponent();
```

This code line appeared in all my Xaml pages' constructors in code behind.
It throws the following error:

> InitializeComponent does not exist.

Now I cannot debug any page in my project although I have commented out this line.

How can I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using Xamarin Forms Portable project.

**Update:** When I comment out this line and run the pages, only an empty screen shows up in both IOS and Android although my pages were working correctly without error before.

**Update 2:** now the InitializeComponent lines are disappeared but the pages that I debug are still totally blank.

I have asked a question about this new problem on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39344199/1136253).

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233582/xamarin-displaying-wrong-images/39236508#39236508

Comment: Dont take care and just run it.

Comment: But when I run the pages, only an empty screen becomes in both IOS and Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change something in the page, then save it.  Scarily this resolves the issue sometime.

If that doesn't work.
Update your nugget packages so Xam Forms is the latest.
"Clean" your project
Go to your project dir and delete the bin and obj from your projects via File Explorer.

Rebuild it.

Good luck.

Comment: I have done these and the InitializeComponent lines have mysteriously become lost from project. But still the pages have totally blank screen when I debug in both Android and IOS.

Comment: I think the logic of changing something in the project, is to saving by hand (simple saving). Some people are doing this for correcting the encoding of file, I don't know it.

Answer (score 9):

I had also the same problem in Xamarin Forms Application.I fixed it by changing the Build Action to:

> Embedded resource

for .xaml and .cs file both using property window.

[image]

Hope it may help you.

Comment: as the comment on previous answer already states, the OP doesn't have this problem. -1 for duplicate answer.

Comment: @Maverik, yes it may be somehow duplicate answer. but the previous answer doesn't state to change the BuildAction as Embedded resource for .xaml and .cs file both.Some times If user change the BuildAction for .xaml file, it doesn't mean the changes will also be applied to .cs file as well. this was the case what i had exactly faced.so i just tried to elaborate a bit more in my answer.

Comment: He may not have said it in words but the screenshot is pretty clear. On top of that asking .cs to be embedded resource is even worse! If people disagree with my assessment, I'm sure somebody will up vote you negating me but my vote stands for now.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that your Xaml page has property `Custom Tool` set to `MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml`

[image]

Comment: Yes I have these values.

Answer (score 1):

'Its not an issue. You can try to build your solution. Hopefully it will bulid perfectly. Most of the time I also get red under line on InitializeComponent(); like you same. Its a problem of Xamarin studio and Visual studio'

Answer (score 1):

Is it the first XAML page you create in the project? or you created other pages and they don't contain this problem?
you can Check the comments here:  http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17638/initializecomponent-does-not-exist/p4

Comment: No I have other pages. This effected all the XAML pages in my project.

Comment: I always find this error when I open the project for the first time, but when I save any XAML page even if I don't make any edits it surprisingly resolve this error, but I don't think this is your problem. One solution is to start a new project and create new files with the same names, sounds strange but sometimes solves these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you renamed your page? All XAML pages have a viewable partial class (the one you enter your logic code in to) and a hidden, system generated partial class.

If you renamed the class but did not use the VS rename macro, your system generated partial class no longer matches your editable partial class.

Try running 'Clean Solution' and 'Rebuild Solution' (both in the 'Build' menu) to see if VS can automatically detect and fix this for you.

If that doesn't work, make sure your pages are set as partial classes e.g. `public partial class MyPage : Page`

If you still have no luck, manually delete the 'obj' folder in your project's root folder, then rebuild again.

Comment: No I didn't rename my pages and classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple trick:**

Just edit your Xaml code..(Put space also enough..But need editing)

After edit the xaml page save project..

Now check error disappears..

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a result of intermediate build paths being too long for Windows. Moving my solution to just off the drive root C:\dev{solution} in my case solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the namespace of my `.xaml` file did not match the namespace of the `.xaml.cs` file. Fixing the namespaces so they matched corrected the problem.